# Access query: iif function error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to count in a column Answers > 8 and in another column < 8 from the same field Answers.[Answer (#)]. The field Answers.[Answer (#)] is survey results on a 1-10 scale. I get the error "cannot have aggregate function in expression (IIf(Answers.[Answer (#)] >8, sum(count(Answers.[Answer (#)])),""))".

In the iif function if I take out sum( the query will count individually 9s and 10s and the same goes for numbers 8 and under. I need those aggregated together in 1 row.

```
SELECT Questions.Year, Questions.[Question Text],
IIf(Answers.[Answer (#)] >8, sum(count(Answers.[Answer (#)])),"") AS Promotors, 
IIf(Answers.[Answer (#)]<=8, sum(Count(Answers.[Answer (#)])),"") AS Detractors
FROM Answers INNER JOIN Questions 
ON Answers.QuestionID = Questions.[Access ID]
WHERE (((Questions.[Question Text]) Like '*Recommend*')) 
and questions.[Question Text] not like '*Are there other technology         services*'
GROUP BY Questions.Year, Questions.[Question Text], Answers.[Answer (#)];
```

Comment: Perhaps `sum(iif(condition, count(...), 0))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Questions.Year, Questions.[Question Text],
       SUM(IIf(Answers.[Answer (#)] > 8, 1, 0) AS Promotors, 
       SUM(IIf(Answers.[Answer (#)] <= 8, 1, 0) AS Detractors
FROM Answers INNER JOIN
     Questions 
     ON Answers.QuestionID = Questions.[Access ID]
WHERE Questions.[Question Text]) Like '*Recommend*' AND
      questions.[Question Text] not like '*Are there other technology         services*'
GROUP BY Questions.Year, Questions.[Question Text];
```

You can't nest aggregation functions.  You want the condition *as the argument* to the function, not on the result.  I also removed the answer column from the `group by`.

Comment: In true condition of second Iif, should `s1` just be `1`?